# route cisco 1841 interface traffic

Tags: networking, interface, cisco, traffic

Below is my 1841 router config, I am trying to get `fa0/1` to send traffic to `fa0/0` which is my comcast modem. The 1841 can send traffic out the wan but `fa0/1` is unable to send traffic over to the wan at `fa0/0`

Building configuration...

```
Current configuration : 1679 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname 3750-POEsw
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$Z/hb$we6fz/oJzImwkttrO9M8a0
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
switch 1 provision ws-c3750-24p
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!         
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!         
!         
!         
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/1
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/2
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/3
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/4
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/5
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/6
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/7
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/8
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/9
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/10
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/11
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/12
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/13
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/14
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/15
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/16
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/17
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/18
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/19
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/20
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/21
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/22
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/23
!         
interface FastEthernet1/0/24
!         
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
!         
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
!         
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.0
!         

3750-POEsw#
3750-POEsw#
3750-POEsw#
*Mar  1 01:48:46.588: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Vlan1, changed state to down
*Mar  1 01:48:47.586: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet1/0/7, changed state to down
3750-POEsw#
*Mar  1 01:48:48.593: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet1/0/7, changed state to down
3750-POEsw#
1841r1#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1500 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 22:24:40 UTC Sun Jul 1 2018
version 15.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname 1841r1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$hB1U$LV3y9.vgMLl.FAgnSOWMV/
!
no aaa new-model
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
!
!
!         
!         
ip dhcp pool default-pool
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 8.8.8.8 
 default-router 10.10.10.1 
!         
!         
ip cef    
no ipv6 cef
!         
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!         
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!         
!         
!         
!         
license udi pid CISCO1841 sn FTX1036W2HR
!         
redundancy
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description comcast modem
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!         
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description lan
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!         
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown 
!         
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!         
!         
ip nat source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
ip nat source static tcp 10.10.10.10 80 interface FastEthernet0/0 80
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
!         
access-list 1 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
control-plane
!         
!         
!         
line con 0
 exec-timeout 30 0
 password admin
 logging synchronous
 login    
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 password admin
 logging synchronous
 login    
 transport input all
!         
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Try following and see if it helps.

no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp